# How to manually cancel a ADF pipeline when an activity fails or completes?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline which has two concurrent list of activities running at the same time lets say the first list of activities has a flag at end which makes the until loop in the second list of activity to complete if flag is true. Now the problem is the flag is set at the end of the pipeline once all the activities in list one is completed.  In case if any one of the activity prior to the set flag activity fails the set flag is never set to TRUE and the until loop runs for infinite time which is not ideal.

Is there a way that I can manually cancel the activity when any one of the activities fails?

Secondly the until loop has an inner wait activity so once it enters the loop it will wait for 50 minutes until it checks for the flag condition next time. The wait is important so I can't exclude the wait however I would want the until loop to end as soon as the flag is set to true even though the wait is running. Basically i'm trying to end the Until loop.

I did try the steps in MS Docs : Pipeline cancel run : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/cancel
But this does not work because even when the RUN ID is correct it says incorrect RUN ID.

Could some one please advise how to achieve this?

Comment: I have studied for a long time. Until activity uses expression `@variables('flag')` to determine whether to execute. Once executed, it seems to be unable to stop the activity.

Comment: Not just until activity. Looks like all the activities cannot be stopped even though the Microsoft document says that we can based on the above link but I havent had any luck it getting that to work.

Comment: Yes, we can't stop the activities,once it started.